# Objective-C method 'imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:'

Tags: swift

Objective-C method 'imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:' provided by method 'imagePickerController(*:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'imagePickerController(*:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' in protocol 'UIImagePickerControllerDelegate'

Code is below. What's wrong? Using Xcode 6.4 Beta.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:NSDictionary!)
```

Answer (score 9):

I had this error after upgrading to swift 2.0. Easy to fix, just retype this method, then auto-complete will guide to the change of parameter types. Now it should be:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: [String: Anyobject]) {
```

Comment: This works with the newest swift version! Thanks. (as of 26-10-2015)

Answer (score 3):

You can try to modified the method as below:
`func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject: AnyObject])`

This is the full example to use this delegate:

```
  func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject: AnyObject]) {

    var image: UIImage!

    // fetch the selected image
    if picker.allowsEditing {
      image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage
    } else {
      image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    }

    // Do something about image by yourself

    // dissmiss the image picker controller window
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

  }
```

Comment: Had to replace "NSDictionary" with [NSObject: AnyObject]

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = pickedImage
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct functionality format for your problem is,

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    {
        // Add your functionality here
    }
```